# Python function works fine except when imported

Tags: python, events, input, joystick, evdev

I've tried to distill this to the essentials.  This code works fine.

```
from evdev import InputDevice, ecodes
dev = InputDevice('/dev/input/event2')   # this is the joystick event file
button = {304: 'A', 305: 'B', 307: 'X', 308: 'Y' }  # Xbox360 button mappings
exit = False

def joystick(dev):
    try:
        for event in list(dev.read()):
            if button[event.code] == 'A' and event.value == 1:
                print('Button A pressed.')
            if button[event.code] == 'X' and event.value == 1:
                print('Button X pressed.')
                return True
    except: pass
    return False
    
while exit == False:
    exit = joystick(dev)
```

However, if I move the joystick function to a separate file (including the proper evdev import) and import it the code breaks (function "joystick" will always return false, not recognizing joystick events).

Any ideas why?  I know the software/hardware interface can be tricky but this is ridiculous.

Comment: Try removing the `try` block and see what causes the function to return `False`.

Comment: The ```try``` is necessary because if there are no events to process an error is thrown and execution stops.

Comment: Try to catch only the specific exception you are expecting, currently you catch everything which might mask the error.

Answer (score 0):

Found the bug.  When I moved the `joystick` function outside of the file I neglected to port the `button` dictionary with it.  The `try` statement masked the error I normally would have gotten by omitting the dictionary.